# How fast could a human pedal a car?

Tags: automotive-engineering, bicycles

Suppose that we were to install bicycle pedals into a passenger car, say a [civic coupe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda_Civic_(eighth_generation)), in such a way that pedaling is [as mechanically efficient as riding an ordinary bike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_performance#Mechanical_efficiency).  Further suppose that we have a transmission with whatever the appropriate gearing would be for actually moving the beast under pedal-power.

What would be the maximum speed of such a vehicle for an ordinary operator [who puts out about 200W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_performance#Energy_output)?

The following variables reduce the ambiguity of the problem... Please comment if more info is necessary:

- Human power output 200W
- Sea level
- 2019 Honda Civic Coupe
- Power lost to friction on gears and whatnot: 0%
- Power lost to road friction and air resistance: 100% at peak velocity

**UPDATE:** To be clear, I am not asking [an open-ended "what if" type question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).  Specifically, I am not open to arbitrary answers about possible things resulting from a pedal-powered car.  I am specifically interested in its speed limitations, which is a well-grounded physics problem.  This is a "practical, answerable question" in the sense that the force input via human pedal-power and the force applied to the car via friction and air resistance are measurable and reasonably well-known quantities.  Therefore, the maximum speed for a given car propelled by an average human operator should have a well-defined and unambiguous value.  In other words, there is one and only one numerical answer to this question, and it is therefore not open-ended.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98664/discussion-on-question-by-scott-how-fast-could-a-human-pedal-a-car).